# link underlining issue in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I added a template to my ASP.Net MVC project, I added all the attached files to the template. In addition, I added all of the calls to the format files (CSS) in layout file, and I removed all the calls related to the default styling files.
After I ran the application, I noticed that all the links `<a>` on the page are underlined, and this thing is not present in the template that I downloaded. I searched for all the attributes responsible for this in CSS files and modified them manually so that this format does not occur, but no changes happens. please any advise??

Comment: maybe these can help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828829/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-get-rid-of-underlined-button-text-when-hovering-over-a

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946613/how-is-bootstrap-v4-loading-reboot-scss

Comment: it worked thank you.. but do you have any idea why this happening? the template is not showing links this why, how it can be changed by it self.

Comment: because of the order of styles matter when they are applied. it seems in the template `style.css` is applied after `_reboot.scss`, but vice versa in your case. If you can reorder your styles, bootstrap before then your custom/template styles after, that should solve the issue or else, simplest solution would be to put an `!important` in your `style.css` and it will solve the issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @CBroe Ok, I deleted them.

Comment: now i got you, many thanks @HarshitT

Comment: I've posted the same as answer, you may accept it and conclude the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of styles matter when they are applied. it seems in the template `style.css` is applied after `_reboot.scss`, but vice versa in your case. If you can reorder your styles, bootstrap before then your custom/template styles after, that should solve the issue or else, simplest solution would be to put an `!important` in your `style.css` and it will solve the issue.